# Combobox background when disabled

Tags: wpf, combobox

I would like to change the background of a combobox when it is disabled (Enabled=true)

I found some article in the net that metioned about controltemplate.

However, it will also remove the dropdown effect as well.

How could I just change the background when disabled with every other things kept at the default stage.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change only one thing in a template, you have to switch out the whole template. Get the default one [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx) (`Default WPF Themes` link), you could modify it accordingly.

You might be able to do this with a simple `Style` and `Trigger` though.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this, you can use a Trigger for your ComboBox style.

Try something like this:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>    
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

---

Looks the ComboBox uses a system resources to set its background. That is what I found out from the [ComboBox control template documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Then try something like this:

```
<ComboBox Margin="149,121,172,164" IsEnabled="False">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="AliceBlue"/>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```